# C++ new if statement with initializer

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++17, initializer

The cppreference page for "if" statement;

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

gives the following example;

> Except that names declared by the init-statement (if init-statement is a declaration) and names declared by condition (if condition is a declaration) are in the same scope, which is also the scope of both statements
>   Blockquote

```
std::map<int, std::string> m;
if (auto it = m.find(10); it != m.end()) { return it->size(); }
```

Thats a typo, isn't it? I'm not missing anything here am I, it should be;

```
it->second.size();
```

or

```
it->first;
```

No?

Comment: Good catch. Fortunately, cppreference.com is a wiki, so you can fix this yourself.

Comment: Thanks @aschlper , I fixed the page in question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is a typo. `iterator` for `std::map` will be dereferenced as `std::map::value_type`, where `value_type` is `std::pair<const Key, T>`.

See example of usage for [`std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) (from cppreference):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
int main()
{  
    std::map<int,char> example = {{1,'a'},{2,'b'}};

    auto search = example.find(2);
    if (search != example.end()) {
        std::cout << "Found " << search->first << " " << search->second << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not found\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are correct. The code as it is given does not compile. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ERfBm3).
The compiler error is:

> ```
> error: 'struct std::pair<const int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' has no member named 'size'
> ```

`std::pair` does not have a `size` member. But `std::string` has it.

So the correct code should be:

```
if (auto it = m.find(10); it != m.end()) { return it->second.size(); }
```